# Documentum 6.7 - JMS Jobs on Jboss 5.1.0 and dependency jar moved from Jboss 4.3.0

Tags: jboss5.x, documentum, jboss-4.2.x

this is a Documentum question but maybe a Jboss expert can help me.

I have the following issue while upgrading Documentum from 6.6 (JMS jboss 4.3.0) to 6.7 (JMS jboss 5.1.0):

**starting environment:**
Documentum 6.6 CS
in

```
/.../jboss4.3.0/server/DctmServer_MethodServer/deploy/ServerApps.ear/DmMethods.war/WEB-INF/lib
```

have to deploy the job-jar (**myJmsJob.jar**)

in

```
/.../jboss4.3.0/server/DctmServer_MethodServer/deploy/lib
```

have to deploy dependecies of myJmsJob (for example **xbeans-2.5.0.jar** and so on).

*I know that in theory i have to avoid to deploy directly on JMS but for 2 jobs I'm forced to.*

**Target environment:**
Documentum 6.7 CS
in

```
/.../jboss5.1.0/server/DctmServer_MethodServer/deploy/ServerApps.ear/DmMethods.war/WEB-INF/lib
```

have to deploy the job-jar (myJmsJob.jar)

but

```
/.../jboss5.1.0/server/DctmServer_MethodServer/deploy/lib
```

does not exist anymore.

A similar directory appears to be

```
/.../jboss5.1.0/server/DctmServer_MethodServer/lib
```

but if i copy my dependecies here, Java throws a **NoClassDefFoundError**

any ideas to solve my problem?

Maybe another directory? Some missing configuration?

Thanx in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried deploying your jars to `%DOCUMENTUM_HOME%\dba\java_methods` and your dependency jars to ext folder of bundled java - usually at `%DOCUMENTUM_HOME%\java\1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext`?

This should work.

---

Author of question - edit: the previus answer is correct however in my case jboss was installed to use an internal jre, so I placed libs in:

```
/...../jboss5.1.0/common/lib
```

that is jboss 5.1.0 common lib default folder
while job in:

```
%DOCUMENTUM_HOME%\dba\java_methods
```

and all works.

Comment: Can you find out which java JBoss is using?

Comment: THank you. On jboss' log i saw it is using and internal java so I finally found out the lib directory. However the "new" path for the job works perfectly.